# C programming , array not printing properly

Tags: c++, c, encryption

So for class we are doing some encryption/ decryption algorithms with prime numbers. I am in the first part of making the program. I am trying to get the program to check if a number is prime or not. After this, I want the program to store all prime numbers before that number in an array called prime_array. And I was trying to get those results to print out on the screen. It's not working the way I intended. I'm later going to use this in decryption of something a bit more complex. Just wandering if anyone could see what part of my code is causing the issues.

Code:

```
  #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        int n;
        int prime;
        int prime_array[1000];
        int prime_answer;
        int j=0;

        printf("enter a number for n : ");
        scanf_s("%d", &n);   

        if (n % 2 == 1)
        {
            printf("Number is prime.");
            getchar();
            getchar();

            for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
            {
                if (n - 1 % 2 == 1)
                {
                    n--;
                    prime_array[j] = n;
                    j++;    
                }
                else
                {
                    // do nothing
                }    
            }    
        }
        else if (n % 2 == 0)
        {
            printf("Number is not prime.");
            getchar();
            getchar();

        }

        for (int k = 0; k<= 10; k++)
        {
            printf("\n\n %d",prime_array[k]);
            if (k == 10);
            {
                getchar();
                getchar();       
            }       
        }        
}
```

Comment: Can't quite understand what you're trying to do with the for loop at the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is this condition-

```
if (n - 1 % 2 == 1)
```

This exression is treated as **`(n-(1 % 2))==1`** , because `%` has *higher precedence* than `-` ,therefore , `1 % 2` is evaluated first .As `1 % 2` is `1` and expression become `n-1`  ,so condition will not be `true` until `n` is `2` (*not as you would desire* ) .

You need to write like this -

```
if ((n - 1) % 2 == 1)
```

Comment: Hmmm, Isn't `(n - 1) % 2 == 1` just about the same as `n % 2 == 0`? (if we ignore negative numbers)

Comment: @chux  That would be similar . Ohh , so if first condition is `true` isn't always iner `else` part be executed  ?